# Custom Preference is recreated when I click to some another (standard) preference (Android)

Tags: android

I have a big problem! I defined a custom Preference in my android application (this preference is called SliderPreference that has a SeekBar inside) and this works fine. But then I use some other element (in my case this is CheckBox) my preference is recreated! How can I escape this nasty effect?

There is the code:

```java
public class SliderPreference extends Preference {
private int value;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private TextView textView;

public SliderPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

    View root = li.inflate( R.layout.preference_seekbar, parent, false); 
    seekBar = (SeekBar)root.findViewById(R.id.pref_seekbar_seekbar);
    textView = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.pref_seekbar_percent);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            if(progress == 0) { seekBar.setProgress(1); progress = 1; }
            double current = (((double)progress/(double)seekBar.getMax())*100f);
            value = (int) Math.round(current);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(value)+"%");
        }
    });
    return root;
}
```

```java
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="hello"/>

    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="Donut settings">

        <com.example.SliderPreference
            android:key=""
            android:title="number"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/pref_seekbar_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/pref_seekbar_percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

```java
public class AndroidPrefs extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```